# How to use .Net WebProxy class

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

I need use the .Net WebProxy class to connect a C# application to internet. My proxy is http://proxy.uh.cu/estudiantes.pac and I'm writing the next lines:

```
var webproxy = new WebProxy("proxy.uh.cu/estudiantes.pac", 80);
webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUserCredential", "myPassword");
```

Am I making any mistake here?